# How to duplicate entries in ExpressionEngine 4?

Tags: duplicate, mx-cloner

Usual options like MX_Cloner seem to have no v4 option. Anyone know of one? Tbh this should are basic functionality by the 4th version now.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh, me too. I found this github cloning tool for EE3, the developer isn't using EE anymore. Maybe it works, maybe it is easy to fix up?

https://github.com/ThorntonStuart/SimpleCloner/issues/18

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using MX Cloner anyways? The upgrade path for EE3 addons to EE4 addons is pretty easy.

Have you tried installing MX Cloner for EE3 on an EE4 copy of the site? There really is a chance it will work out of the box or require little developer time to make compatible.

No guarantee, but worth a shot.

Comment: I doubt this approach would work well as the channel/field logic has changed significantly from EE3 to EE4.